# Finding a higher dimensional analogue to 1D Sobolev space identity

Tags: vector-analysis, sobolev-spaces, divergence-theorem

I had solved a previous problem on $H^1_0(0,1)$ using the identity
$$
\int_0^1 b(x)u'(x) u(x) = -\frac{1}{2} \int_0^1 b'(x) u(x)^2.
$$

Is there any analogue to this for nice domains $\Omega$ where we have
$$
\int_\Omega [\overset{\to}{b}(x)\cdot\nabla u(x)] u(x) = -\frac{1}{2}\int_\Omega \nabla \cdot \overset{\to}{b}(x) u(x)^2.
$$
I'm rusty on vector calculus, but I think I need the divergence theorem somewhere.

Comment: Hint: Use the identity $$\nabla\cdot(\vec{b}u^2)=(\nabla\cdot\vec{b}\,)u^2+\vec{b}\cdot\nabla u^2.$$

Comment: In the first one, I used $$ \int buu'  = \int -(bu)'u = -\int b'u^2 - \int buu'.$$ I'm trying to see how to use this one since we went right to the squares of $u$.